# Mysql select specific range of datetime

Tags: php, mysql

how can i select all the rows of "buydate" that are in a date range (from 14:00 PM of yesterday to 10:00 AM of today) in mysql using php? Thanks

```
Table log: id(int), users(varchar), buydate (datetime)
```

Comment: @chenci Do you really mean from yesterday or do you mean from the day before?

Comment: similar to answer below using between. But i need relative date (the day before and today)

Comment: Ok, answered based on a relative date

Comment: try updated answer and let me know if it works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below

`select * from log where buydate BETWEEN '2012-02-27 14:00' AND '2012-02-28 10:00'`

As I don't have MYSQL now I won't be able to check...

### Update 1

You don't need to add dates now... It WILL work

```
SELECT * from log 
WHERE buydate BETWEEN date_add(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day), interval 14 hour) and date_add(curdate(), interval 10 hour)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but as i posted above, i need relative date (that's why i use yesterday and today)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * from log
where buydate between 
  date_add(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day), interval 14 hour) and
  date_add(curdate(), interval 10 hour)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add it in to the `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE buydate BETWEEN '2012-02-27 14:00' AND '2012-02-28 10:00'
```

The string is automagically coerced into a datetime for comparison.

You can do more complicated date calculations using the MySQL [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).